# Проверка на сравнение наложения изображения Java

Tags: java, изображения

Есть игра, где сверху падают фрукты, а ваза их ловит. Ваза и фрукты представлены изображениями (`BufferedImage`) размером 100x100. Как проверить, что ваза поймала фрукт?

P.S. Не надо писать про проверку на равенство `x` и `y`, `у` подставки и фрукта.

Comment: А почему `не надо писать про проверку на равенство x и y, у подставки и фрукта`?

Comment: @diraria , потому что мне надо чтобы если одно изображение(фрукт) хоть немного задело другое изображение(подставку),то засчитывалось очко. А если проверять строго по x и y,то изображение одно должно точно наложиться на другое.

Answer (score 3):

Надо создать прямоугольники `Rect` с координатами фруктов и вазочки и проверить их пересечение методом `intersect()`:

```
Rect fruit, vase;
if(vase.intersect(fruit))
   //bingo! есть пересечение
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, он хочет по картинкам проверять с учётом прозрачных областей, а не просто прямоугольники?

Comment: *Ваза и фрукты представлены изображениями (BufferedImage) размером 100x100* - ничего не говорилось о прозрачных областях

Comment: А можно как - то сделать,чтобы прямоугольники были,но их не было видно ?

Comment: Надеюсь, это вы так шутите :)

Comment: `Rect` это объект, который создается на основе изображения, он не имеет отношения к рисованию - совсем...

Comment: @Barmaley, а понял. Извиняюсь за тупизм :) Спасибо.

Comment: @Barmaley, начал реализовывать вдруг как вдруг наткнулся на то,что Rect находится в пакете android, я может что-то не понимаю,но как мне кажется в приложении для компьютера этот пакет не используется.

Comment: Если у вас обычный Java - то тогда используйте `java.awt.Rectangle` у него тоже есть метод `intersection()`

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо!